# Effectively using $.when.apply(...) on custom promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm using $.when.apply(methodArray[...]) in order to return the method callback arguments in my overall "done" callback.   This works fine when the methods are $.ajax(options) calls, but sometimes the member methods are synchronous.   I've tried every combination of $.Deferred, new Promise, $.when().then(...) that I can come up with, but I simply can't get the data from my sync call to show up as arguments in my done() callback.   Here's an abbreviated example:

```
var loader() {

    var obj = this;

    this.execute = function (force, success, fail) {

        if (!force) {
            var data = {message: "This is cached data"};
            if (data) {
                //this does not return data to when.apply
                return $.when().done(function () {
                    if (success) success(data);
                    return data;
                });
            }
        }
        return execute(success, fail); //this works fine
    }

    function execute(success, fail) {

        return $.ajax({
            type: obj.method,
            url: obj.url,
            data: obj.data,
            dataType: obj.dataType || "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (obj.cacheName) setCacheData(obj.cacheName, data);
                if (obj.success) obj.success(data);
                if (success) success(data);
            },
            fail: function (err) {
                if (obj.fail) obj.fail(err);
                if (fail) fail(err);
            }
        });
    }
}

var selected = []  //array of loader objects with "execute(...)" command

$.when.apply($, $.map(selected, function (l) {
            return l.execute(force, l.success, l.fail);
        })).done(function () {
            if (success) success($.map(arguments, function (a) {
                return a[0];   //a is undefined on sync method
            }));
        }).fail(function () {
            if (fail) fail($.map(arguments, function (a) {
                return a[0];  
            }));
        });
```

Basically, after the first (ajax) call, the data is cached.  On subsequent calls, the "execute" function will just get the data from cache instead of the ajax call.

As mentioned - the when.apply code above works perfectly when the "execute" command is returning an $.ajax call.    But when it is returning data that is cached (ie: from a previous ajax call) I cannot get the data passed back in the callback arguments.

How do I write this "execute" function to return EITHER the cached data or the $.ajax call as a promise - so that it is transparent (no difference) to the "when.apply"??

Another way I tried it:

```
            if (data) {
                var df = $.Deferred();
                if (success) success(data);
                df.resolve(data);
                return df.promise(data);
            }
```

That also did not work...

Comment: This is very hard to figure out without seeing the actual code. My guess (from the code presented and your 'a is undefined' line) would be that there is no return statement in your `then(function(data) {...})` call. This would produce `undefined` in the `a` at the location you mentioned. But again, a working (that is, not working) example would be nice.

Comment: Hi Spiny - thanks.  I am returning data inside the .done...  I've edited the code post to contain the actual code (except "data" is set to an example object, instead of the function call which actually gets the cached data)